# Including git commit hash and date in webpack build

Tags: angular, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm using react/es6/webpack. I want to show the date of the build and git hash somewhere in my app. What's the best approach?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use webpack's [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/):

```
// get git info from command line
let commitHash = require('child_process')
  .execSync('git rev-parse --short HEAD')
  .toString()
  .trim();

...
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __COMMIT_HASH__: JSON.stringify(commitHash)
    })
  ]
...
```

Then you can use it in your app with `__COMMIT_HASH__`

Comment: To make ESLint happy I had to add `globals: { __COMMIT_HASH__: true }` to my `.eslintrc` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39053582/1054633)

Comment: had to play with the `.eslintrc` : ```{
    "globals": {
        "__COMMIT_HASH__": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module",
      "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
    }
}```

Comment: I put a `.trim()` at the end of the method chain of `commitHash` to remove a new line character.

Comment: why JSON.stringify is required?

Comment: @echo because the values are inserted directly into the code during build time, and JSON.stringify wraps the values in quotes producing a string syntax. Hopefully someone can correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: If using Typescript, you might have to create a `global.d.ts` file and add that to your `tsconfig.json` to get the global declared.

Follow:
https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/modules/globals

Comment: I had to restart webpack dev server before using `__COMMIT_HASH__`

Comment: To add a dirty flag, see here: https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/10/12/check-git-dirty/

Answer (score 33):

**Another way of doing this is ( in ANGULAR + REACT ) :**

Just install this package [git-revision-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-revision-webpack-plugin)

> Simple webpack plugin that generates VERSION and COMMITHASH files
>   during build based on a local git repository.

---

Sample Code :

**Inside your webpack.config.js (or any dev - prod file)**

```
const GitRevisionPlugin = require('git-revision-webpack-plugin');
const gitRevisionPlugin = new GitRevisionPlugin();

plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      'VERSION': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.version()),
      'COMMITHASH': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.commithash()),
      'BRANCH': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.branch()),
    }),
  ]
```

**In your Component (React):**

```
export class Home extends Component{
    ....

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {VERSION} 
                {COMMITHASH}
                {BRANCH}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**In your Template (Angular):**

```
{{ VERSION }} 
{{ COMMITHASH }}
{{ BRANCH }}
```

Comment: if webpack is in watch mode and keeping running, how to update such git information when a new git commit/pull is made?

Comment: `watch` mode is meant for the source files in the project, not the git repository. I'm guessing `watch-poll` is the only valid option for changes not related to source files.

Comment: sorry being late for party. @raptoravis probably answer you were looking for is here -- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7717#issuecomment-460653171

Comment: I run my webpack build, and *then* I commit. The problem is that GitRevisionPlugin's `COMMITHASH` will be the *previous* commit, not the *current* commit. How to solve this?

Comment: If using typescript, then you will have to declare global variables like so:
`declare var COMMITHASH: string;` and install the corresponding @types package:
`@types/git-revision-webpack-plugin`. Also, I would recommend using a unique global variable name like `__COMMIT_HASH___`

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't comment to the top post, so here goes:

**Webpack.dev.js**

```
import gitprocess from "child_process"
let LoadCommitDate = gitprocess
  .execSync('git log -1 --date=format:"%Y/%m/%d %T" --format="%ad"')
  .toString()
...
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       COMMITDATE: JSON.stringify(LoadCommitDate),
    })
  ]
```

Additionally in **.eslintrc**

```
  "globals": {
    "COMMITDATE": "readonly",
  },
```

**Result - latest commit date you can reference in your code!**

```
console.log(COMMITDATE)
2020/05/04 21:02:03
```

Comment: `declare const COMMITDATE: string` use this in @types/global.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add the hash as a comment in my index.html. Found a way to do that with html-webpack-plugin and the [templateParameters](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/main/examples/template-parameters) option.

In the top of your webpack config:

```
// get git info from command line
const commitHash = require('child_process')
  .execSync('git rev-parse --short HEAD')
  .toString()
  .trim()
```

The further down where you initiate HtmlWebpackPlugin:

```
templateParameters: {
  __COMMIT_HASH__: JSON.stringify(commitHash),
}
```

Finally somewhere in your index.html template:

```
<!-- <%= __COMMIT_HASH__ %> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**2 steps** to get commit info in a clean & useful way.

Step 1: Add Package

```bash
npm install --save-dev react-git-info
```

Step 2: Usage in Component file

```js
// MyComponent.js
import GitInfo from 'react-git-info/macro';

function MyComponent() {
  
  const gitInfo = GitInfo();

  return (
    <div data-branch={gitInfo.branch}>
       {gitInfo.commit.hash}
    </div>
  );
}
```