# ESLint no-undef and webpack plugin

Tags: webpack, eslint

I use webpack plugin:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({              
            PUBLIC_KEY:'\'XXX\'',
            CLIENT_ID: '\'XXXX\''
        })



tgc.init({
            publicKey: PUBLIC_KEY,
            clientId: CLIENT_ID     
        });
```

I use eslint and use `Disallow Undeclared Variables (no-undef)` rule, so when I write

```
tgc.init({
            publicKey: PUBLIC_KEY,
            clientId: CLIENT_ID     
    });
```

I get errors:

> 'PUBLIC_KEY' is not defined
>   'CLIENT_ID' is not edfined

How to avoid it? I don't want to disable this rule (with disabled rule all works fine)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add:

```
  "globals": {
    "PUBLIC_KEY": true,
    "CLIENT_ID": true,
  }
```

to your `eslint.rc` -file.

or you can do the same in your webpack config -file as an inline comment like:

```
/* global PUBLIC_KEY, CLIENT_ID */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe I was unclear. eslint throw error about `PUBLIC_KEY` and `CLIENT_ID`.

Comment: Edited the answer.. btw, you really should keep that kind of variables as an process env vars. See: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

Comment: Should be `"readonly"` instead of `true` as the variables are not modifiable, and the use of `true` and `false` is deprecated: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#using-configuration-files-1