# How to use environment variables that were defined in Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, webpack.config.js

I am currently trying to add Google oauth to a React App I am creating. However I am running into a problem. I have defined some variables in my webpack but when I add them to my react code they are coming up as undefined.

React component code

```
let googleLoginBaseUrl = 'https://www.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth'
    let googleLoginQuery = stringify({
        client_id: __GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID__,
        response_type: 'code',
        redirect_uri: `${__API_URL__}/oauth/google/code`,
        scope: 'openid profile email',
        prompt: __DEBUG__ ? 'consent' : undefined,
    })

    let googleLoginUrl = `${googleLoginBaseUrl}?${googleLoginQuery}`
```

Webpack.config.js code

```
let plugins = [
  new EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV']),
  new ExtractPlugin('bundle-[hash].css'),
  new HTMLPlugin({template: `${__dirname}/src/index.html`}),
  new DefinePlugin({
    __DEBUG__: JSON.stringify(!production),
    __API_URL__: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
    __GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID__: JSON.stringify(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID),
  }),
]

if (production)
  plugins = plugins.concat([ new CleanPlugin(), new UglifyPlugin() ])

module.exports = {
  plugins,
```

Compiling Error

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Login/login.js
  Line 10:24:  '__GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID__' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 12:30:  '__API_URL__' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 14:21:  '__DEBUG__' is not defined             no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that there is not javascript compile error, but only ESLint reported error. Probably you have set up your build process such way, that some eslint error stops your build process.

I can confirm that using variables defined with DefinePlugin in the app is reported by ESLint as an `no-undef` error.

Try to disble this ESLint rule, put `/* eslint-disable no-undef */` on the first line of your `./src/components/Login/login.js`.

Or you can add your defined variables to `globals` section in your eslint config file, see this answer:
[ESLint no-undef and webpack plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053562/eslint-no-undef-and-webpack-plugin?rq=1#answer-39053582)

Comment: So page is now building but the environment variables defined by DefinePlugin are still seen as undefined

Comment: I can confirm, that DefinePlugin it is working correctly with your syntax, isn't a problem with your values of that variables in the DefinePlugin? What happen if you try to put simple value in variable (e.g. `__DEBUG__ : JSON.stringify('Just for testing')`)? Check your built bundle, if the replacement occurred (search for the string 'Just for testing').